# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos y\sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos y\sin x$$
I really don't know where to start since I don't know how to integrate $\sec y$ which I would have to do if I treated it as a separable equation. Please help

Comment: All trigonometric functions have integrals. You could use some cheat sheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\int \sec(x) \; dx = \int \sec(x) \frac{\sec(x) + \tan(x)}{\sec(x) + \tan(x)}\; dx
$$
Then think substitution (recall the derivatives of $\sec$ and $\tan$).

Comment: (This is kind of a "clever trick" that's only used when integrating $\sec(x)$.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw: I agree. It is (sort of) also used when integrating cosecant.

Comment: …right. Forgot about that one. Point still stands (more-or-less), though.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that the antiderivative of $\sec(y)$ is $\ln| \sec(y) + \tan(y) | + C$. This can be demonstrated as in @Thomas's answer.

Another approach is the following:

$$\int \sec(y) dy = \int \frac{1}{\cos(y)} dy = \int \frac{\cos(y)}{\cos^2(y)} dy = \int \frac{\cos(y)}{1-\sin^2(y)} dy$$

Then the substitution $u=\sin(y)$ gives:

$$=\int \frac{du}{1-u^2} = \frac12 \int \frac{du}{1-u} + \frac12 \int \frac{du}{1+u}.$$

You can complete the antiderivative from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can just memorize it from [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions#Integrands_involving_only_secant) (it's not hard)

$$ \int \sec x\,dx = \ln|\sec x + \tan x| + C$$